# Calling class from vendor

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**EDIT** Autoload

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

I am calling it this way:

```
$generatorSVG = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorSVG();
```

The error:

> Message: Class 'Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorSVG' not found

The class exist. I am not installing it via composer but copying it in the vendor folder, because I dont have composer and the server and dont have permissions to install it.
Using PHPStorm and by ctrl+click on the class leads me to it. I am wrong with the proper calling it in CI ?

Comment: Hi you can set composer auto path in config.php file autoload.  don't use require in you library or controller

Comment: Sadly tried with it. But result was the same..

Answer (score 1):

Manually copying files in the vendor directory is not enough, because Composer generates a bunch of lookup files (vendor/composer/autoload_*.php) to be able to figure out where the files are located that you want to load via Composer's autoloader.

Either, you should composer require the package you want to install or require all your source files manually in your bootstrap.php or index.php.
If this is a custom package you built, be aware that Composer can also pull it directly from a Git instance, local directory, or zip file. There's no need to  create a public package on Packagist or self-host it with Satis. Check the Composer docs on how to configure repositories to find out more.